# mysql restoring data on localmachine where the password is empty

Tags: mysql

I use a ruby program to download data from staging server and to populate that data to my local mysql server where the userid is root and password is empty.

```
cmd = "mysql -u #{user}  -p'#{password}' my_db < out.sql"
```

Since password is empty, I get prompted for password. I just have to hit enter. I would like to avoid that. What's the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the -p option.